# Exception cast from a different project

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey this is the weirdest problem i've ever encoutered,
I have 2 projects that's exactly the same each in a different project with a different package name.

Now i'm trying to run the 2nd project and i get a NullPointerException and when i press the error for it to send me to the line of code, it loads the same activity but in a different project.

Any idea why that happens?

This is my manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="shibby.koteret"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TenKoteretActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/chosen_image" android:name="selectedImageActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             />
         <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

         </application>

</manifest>
```

Which is exactly the same in both projects besides package name and main activity name.

This is the logcat :

```
    06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1886, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/45 }} to activity {shibby.koteret/shibby.koteret.selectedImageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at shibby.koteret.selectedImageActivity.onActivityResult(selectedImageActivity.java:196)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
06-26 21:02:38.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5237):     ... 11 more
```

I don't think it's related, but as asked this is the relavent Java code (Errors on setContentView):

```
    setContentView(R.layout.chosen_image);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.chosenImage2);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

What i've checked :

- The 2nd project packages the activity to the write project
- I am not importing any thing from the 1st project package

Could this be an Eclipse error only? Anyone ever seen such a problem?

I was thinking, as the error is on an XML file, could it be somehow related to the R?

Comment: I don't think it's related but i added the relavent code anyway...

Comment: I had a similar problem. What worked for me so far was to just close the other project in eclipse (right click on project -> close), and just open it as needed....

Comment: Ya was just about to write i solved it the same way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what worked for me was i closed the 1st project and then Eclipse sent me to the right NullPointerException.

Still no idea why that happened, but that did the trick for me.